References for Term Functor Logic
Can anyone here point me to some works on term functor logic? I ask because I want to read up on it and figure out how quantifiers work in term functor logic. Also, from what I read, it seems to mimic Boolean algebra as how Boole originally wrote and intended it.

I suppose that you can start  from Predicate functor logic with ref to Sommers, Quine and Kuhn.

Quantifiers just more or less work the same way, it's the term functor part alleviating some burdens off predicates and become much more expressive yet at the same time introduces undecidability potentially...
